# Number of ways to arrange objects in a circle, some of which may be identical

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, necklace-and-bracelets

I know that the number of ways to arrange $n$ distinct objects in a circle in $(n-1)!$ from [Circular Permutation](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CircularPermutation.html).

But suppose we have $n_1$ identical objects of Type $1$, $n_2$ identical objects of Type $2$ and so on upto $n_k$ identical objects of Type $k$, with the total number of objects equal to $n$. How many ways are there to arrange these objects in a circle?

I tried selecting the first object in $1$ (say of Type $1$) way (since it is a circle) and then considering the remaining objects to be permuted in a line, so we get the total number of ways as: $$\dfrac{(n-1)!}{(n_1 - 1)! n_2 ! \cdots n_k !} + \dfrac{(n-1)!}{n_1 ! (n_2 - 1)! \cdots n_k !} + \cdots + \dfrac{(n-1)!}{n_1! n_2 ! \cdots (n_k-1) !}$$

But this is clearly an overcount, since if we take the problem of arranging $9$ blue and $3$ red beads in a circle, the answer we get from the above is $\dfrac{11!}{8! \cdot 3!} + \dfrac{11!}{9! \cdot 2!} = 220$, while the correct answer (from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2395407/130750)) is $19$.

Can anyone solve the general case?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Answer:
$$
\text{# arrangements } = \frac1{n}\sum_{d|\gcd(n_1,\dots,n_k)}\varphi(d)\binom{n/d}{n_1/d,\dots,n_k/d}
$$

There are (at least) two general methods for solving problems of this type: [Burnside's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside%27s_lemma) (which was mentioned in the solution by N.F. Taussig in the question you linked to) and the [Polya Enumeration Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%B3lya_enumeration_theorem).  I will illustrate the use of the Polya method in the case of $9$ blue balls and $3$ red balls arranged around a circle.  We want to count the distinct arrangements.

The group of symmetries in the case of $12$ objects arranged around a circle is the cyclic group of order $12$, $C_{12}$.  In general, for a cyclic group of order $n$, the cycle index is
$$Z = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{d|n} \phi(d) x_d^{n/d}$$
where the summation takes place over all divisors $d$ of $n$ and $\phi(d)$ is the Euler Phi function.  For the case of $n=12$, we have
$$Z = \frac{1}{12} (x_1^{12} + x_2^6 + 2 x_3^4 + 2x_4^3 +2 x_6^2 +4x_{12})$$
Using the variables $b$ and $r$ to denote the colors blue and red, we have after "substitution" (replacing $x_i$ with $b^i+r^i$)
$$Z = \frac{1}{12}((b + r)^{12} + (b^2 + r^2)^6 + 2 (b^3 + r^3)^4 + 2 (b^4 + r^4)^3 + 2 (b^6 + r^6)^2 + 4 (b^{12} + r^{12}))$$
which after expansion becomes
$$Z = b^{12}+b^{11} r+6 b^{10} r^2+19 b^9 r^3+43 b^8 r^4+66 b^7 r^5+80 b^6 r^6+66 b^5 r^7+43 b^4
   r^8+19 b^3 r^9+6 b^2 r^{10}+b r^{11}+r^{12}$$
The coefficient of $b^i r^j$ in this polynomial is the number of distinct arrangements using $i$ blue balls and $j$ red balls.  Since the coefficient of $b^9 r^3$ is $19$, the answer to the original problem is $19$.  But notice that we have simultaneously solved the problem for all possible combinations of $12$ balls in two colors; for example, the number of arrangements with $7$ blue balls and $5$ red balls is $66$.

If you apply this in general when the distribution type is given by the vector $(n_1,\dots,n_k)$, the result works out to be the answer quoted at the top.

One source of examples of the use of Polya's Enumeration Theorem is *Schaum's Theory and Problems of Combinatorics* by V.K. Balakrishnan.

Answer (score 0):

Say you first choose a blue ball and then count distinct line permutation of 8 identical blue balls and 3 red balls. As an example, the following will be counted as distinct case even though they are the same in circular permutation.

B BBBBRRRBBBB

B BBBRRRBBBBB